# Column depending of other columns

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
year V2 V3 V4 V5       V6     V7
1    1  1  8  2000000  78888  135555556
2    1  1  8  2111111  16888  0
3    1  1  8  2222222  12777  0
4    1  1  8  2333333  12222  0
5    1  1  8  1444444  77777  0
6    1  1  8  5555555  26666  0
7    1  1  8  2111111  22222  0
8    1  1  8  2666666  34444  0
```

If `year > 1` then `v7` should be equal to `v7 - v6` of the year before. This should be done for each group of `v2`, `v3` and `v4`.

Resulting in this:

```
year V2 V3 V4 V5       V6     V7
1    1  1  8  2000000  78888  135555556
2    1  1  8  2111111  16888  135476668
3    1  1  8  2222222  12777  135459780
4    1  1  8  2333333  12222  135447003
5    1  1  8  1444444  77777  135434781
6    1  1  8  5555555  26666  135357004
7    1  1  8  2111111  22222  135330338
8    1  1  8  2666666  34444  135308116
```

How can I construct a function that produces that output?

Comment: The part where you try to explain what you want to do for `v7` makes no sense. Can you please be more clear to what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `cumsum` and `head`.

```
df$V7 <- head(df$V7, 1) - c(0, head(cumsum(df$V6), -1))
```

The cumulative sum of V6 (except the final value) is subtracted from the first element of V7. The subsets of the vectors are obtained using `head`.

This returns

```
df
  year V2 V3 V4      V5    V6        V7
1    1  1  1  8 2000000 78888 135555556
2    2  1  1  8 2111111 16888 135476668
3    3  1  1  8 2222222 12777 135459780
4    4  1  1  8 2333333 12222 135447003
5    5  1  1  8 1444444 77777 135434781
6    6  1  1  8 5555555 26666 135357004
7    7  1  1  8 2111111 22222 135330338
8    8  1  1  8 2666666 34444 135308116
```

If you need to perform this by group (which is not in your example), you could use the split-apply-combine method.

```
do.call(c, lapply(split(df, df[c("V2", "V3", "V4")]),
                  function(x) {head(x$V7, 1) - c(0, head(cumsum(x$V6), -1))}))
```

This assumes that each group of V2 V3 V4 starts with year 1.

**data**

```
df <- 
structure(list(year = 1:8, V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), V3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V4 = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), V5 = c(2000000L, 2111111L, 2222222L, 2333333L, 
1444444L, 5555555L, 2111111L, 2666666L), V6 = c(78888L, 16888L, 
12777L, 12222L, 77777L, 26666L, 22222L, 34444L), V7 = c(135555556L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("year", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(V7=first(V7)- cumsum(lag(V6, default = 0)))
#  year V2 V3 V4      V5    V6        V7
#1    1  1  1  8 2000000 78888 135555556
#2    2  1  1  8 2111111 16888 135476668
#3    3  1  1  8 2222222 12777 135459780
#4    4  1  1  8 2333333 12222 135447003
#5    5  1  1  8 1444444 77777 135434781
#6    6  1  1  8 5555555 26666 135357004
#7    7  1  1  8 2111111 22222 135330338
#8    8  1  1  8 2666666 34444 135308116
```

and if we need to do this by group

```
df %>%
   group_by(.dots = names(df)[2:4]) %>%
   mutate(V7=first(V7)- cumsum(lag(V6, default = 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (i in 2:length(df$V7)) {
   if (df$year[i] > 1) {
     df$V7[i] <- df$V7[i-1] - df$V6[i-1]
   }
 }

 df
  year V2 V3 V4      V5    V6        V7
1    1  1  1  8 2000000 78888 135555556
2    2  1  1  8 2111111 16888 135476668
3    3  1  1  8 2222222 12777 135459780
4    4  1  1  8 2333333 12222 135447003
5    5  1  1  8 1444444 77777 135434781
6    6  1  1  8 5555555 26666 135357004
7    7  1  1  8 2111111 22222 135330338
8    8  1  1  8 2666666 34444 135308116
```